# Identical package names in different folders for same project

Tags: go

I'm working on a big project which will likely end up containing tens of thousands of line of code, for the current structure I do like this:

```
main.go
controllers/NAME.go
models/NAME.go
```

The problem with that is that the controllers and models directory contains a lot of files, all using `package controllers` and `package models`. I was therefore thinking about splitting it up like this:

```
main.go
controllers/user/NAME.go
models/user/NAME.go
```

Where the user files in the controllers package might contain files like `routes.go`, `profile.go`, etc.

Now, I read that it's bad practice to name packages like `controllersUser` or `controllers_user`, but I worry it might be a bad idea to name both as `package user` since they're a part of the same project (even if they're located in different directories).

What kind of naming structure would you recommend given my situation?

I realize that the files located in controllers/user will not be able to interact with models/user even through they share the same `package user` name (unless I import of course), and I also know that I can easy import both as `userControllers "controllers/user"` and `userModels "models/user"`, but I wonder if it's a bad practice to do like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you read [style guideline for Go packages](https://rakyll.org/style-packages/). It's a fantastic read and contains the best advice I found on the subject when it comes to project layout in Go. I'm having hard times suggesting you a naming for your specific case though because it depends too much on the kind of functionality your system has. Sometimes, I think of it as a "package per part of the application". But I understand my description may result too personal and not very helpful.

Comment: I agree with that article, and I have also been able to tell from personal experience that throwing it all into a `controllers` package will become a disaster as the codebase continue to increase. but from what I can understand, there's nothing wrong with having two `package user` where one is located with the other controller files, and the other with the model files?

Comment: I think it goes against the idea you have one package for responsability. The author uses user as a suggestion in the paragraph. ` package mngtservice` with all the code related to the user responsability in your system

Comment: Hmm, on one hand I feel it would be smart to make a package called `users` which contained files like `router.go`, `models.go`, `profile.go`, `register.go`, etc.. on the other hand, that would mean abandoning the MVC structure where I can nicely place these directories inside models and controllers directories. How would you suggest naming the directory which contained all these web-app related features if I can't place them inside controllers/models directories?

Comment: I personally called api in my latest project. It contains all the code for setting up endpoints, cors, different kind of requests. Maybe web? It's a bit too generic though. Naming is so hard! :)

Comment: Hah yeah, I considered `web`, `app`, `modules`, `routes`, etc., but it doesn't give me the same satisfaction as `models` and `controllers`.. but thanks for everything, I think my project structure will improve a lot thanks to you :)

Comment: You're more than welcome. All the credit goes to rakyll though. I learn something every times she publishes an article!